# Design question - update several rows with c# - concern on multiple round trips performance

Tags: c#, .net, database, web-services

I've got an existing website (based on .net 1.1), that calls web-services (based on .net 1.1) to access data.  The web-services call stored procedures to run the SQL.

I have a parent object (letter) with a number of child objects (comments) (5-25) and I need to update one column on each of the child objects to a new value - setting a flag on the comments to set the status as approved for instance - this property is on the comments, not the letter, as further unapproved comments can be added later.

The usual approach we'll take is to create a new webmethod e.g. ApproveComments and pass in the letterID, to set all the comments currently on the letter to approved.  Then an ApproveCommentsOnLetter stored procedure is called to UPDATE the ApprovedFlag to True where letterID = the passed in parameter.

This approach means that over time we tend to end up with lots of very specific webservice calls and very specific stored procedures as new functionality is added in a particular area of the system.  This works ok, but means we're always writing new code and I'm thinking about how we could do things differently.  I can't change the .net version for what at the moment is a small change, but am considering how to approach things differently as we continue updating this application over time.

The idea I've had is to instead create a more generic webmethod called UpdateComments, that would be used for all updates to comments.  I would pass an array of Comments objects into this, which would have get/set properties.  In this case I would loop through and update the Status property on each to True before sending them to the web-method, but in the future other columns could be set in a similar way, avoiding creating new web-methods.

I'm then stumbling a bit with the database section.  It feels like the next step would be to have an UpdateComment stored procedure.  I'd then have to call this multiple times, once for each comment in turn to be updated.  I'm concerned that making a number of repeated round-trips to the database for these calls (5-25 currently) isn't very efficient and just generally feels *bad*.  The other approach though that I can see is for these 'bulk' updates to go back to having a specific web-method and stored procedure dedicated to updating a given property at a time, but then I'm back where I started with creating new web-methods and stored procedures for each new functionality we add to the front-end.

I'd be grateful for thoughts on how to approach this - I can't go and add an ORM / new version of .net / etc. so need to think about how best to approach this within the confines of the technologies I already have in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the next step would be to have an UpdateComment stored procedure. I'd then have to call this multiple times

That's just it - the database does not handle collections of rows, while the webservice is primarily interested in a collection of rows.

If you can move from stored procedures to app-controlled data modification, there's nothing that says you can't package multiple update statements into a SqlCommand's text.

Or if that's not an option, there's nothing that says you can't call a stored proc many times in one round trip.

Comment: "Or if that's not an option, there's nothing that says you can't call a stored proc many times in one round trip." - my fellow developers are getting concerned that on average calling the same proc 5 times per user action (and potentially up to 25 times), is a) bad for performance and b) just bad.  I don't have performance figures to backup either approach (as I haven't built it yet), so would be interested in if this is 'premature optimisation' or a significant concern with this approach.

Comment: There is certainly a performance difference for round-tripping many times.  There's also a (smaller) performance difference for using many update statements when 1 statement will do.  Whether it's premature or not is really app dependant: 25 roundtrips might be ok for many apps; 50,000 roundtrips is probably not ok for most apps.  Any optimization without measurement is technically premature.

Answer (score 1):

@Durator

If I were you I'd continue down the path of making specific calls into the web service rather than try and make generic kinds of calls. It may be a bit of work but in the long run it pays off as the system is a lot more maintainable and in fact you've provided an abstraction layer that is business centric. That is, from a business process perspective the process is to approve comments for a given letter. A specific method to do that makes it very clear and maps to the business process.

Now as far as multiple round trips are concerned...
Your web service could accept an array of comment ids along with the letter id. That way, you've made one call across the wire that contains the letter id and an array of comment ids that you need to update.

The implementation of that could be done in a few ways.
1. Send your stored proc the array of ids delimited with commas and them in the sp, split the ids and do the updates.

If you're using MS SQL server 2008, then there is a new variable type called a TableValueParameter or TVP. Essentially, you can send your storped proc a .NET DataTable that contains the records you want to send (columns and rows) and in the SP you treat the parameter as a "table" so you can do joins on it it use it to do your updates.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight it does seem that making one call per row isn't the right way to go - but I suggest you try it and see. It's certainly the simplest and you may find that there is no user-perceived performance problem once you get into production.